# how to send URL in Watson conversation?

Tags: watson-conversation, watson-dialog

I am building a chat bot to send URL in Watson conversation bot which can sometime send URL of the required information.

Comment: Have you done any work? Can you show it?

Comment: URLs can be set in the Watson Response part as a text, so this should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can send in your message as Follows.

```
{
  "context": {
    "msg": "My URL",
    "url": "http://someURL/"
  }
}
```